# How translate URL slug and apply it on htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, translation

Is that possible to translate URL slug via **htaccess** and **php**?
for example:

```
http://www.example.com/sr/Arheoloski-lokaliteti.html --> index.php?lang=sr
```

click on an icon with EN flag, and redirect to here:

```
http://www.example.com/en/Arheoloski-locality.html --> index.php?lang=en
```

**Arheoloski-lokaliteti** translate to **Arheoloski-locality** automatically (via API or something) but how apply htaccess rewrite on it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    RewriteEngine On
     # The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
     # exists, simply serve it.
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
     RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
     RewriteRule ([^\/.]*).*\/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

And then index.php

```
    <?php
        $language = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : "default";
        $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : "default";
        switch($language){
              case "en":
                  //logic to pull appropriate content based on $page value 
                  break;

              case "sr":
                  //logic to pull appropriate content based on $page value
                  break;

              default:
                  //logic to pull appropriate content based on $page value
                  break;
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: Thank you but main part of my issue is translating (from language a to language b) the URL :/

Comment: try `RewriteRule ([^\/.]*).*\/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]` instead of last line. and in index.php try to map $_GET['page'] with equivalent name in another language.